# Unity 5.6 doesn't open the project - requires re-import

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project 5.6, when I try to open in unity 5.6, an error message appears, asking to do the re-import, when accepting the project opens but nothing appears, all the files and everything that was done in the project simply disappears. Has anyone ever experienced this? What could I do? I need to open this project correctly.
Thanks guys

Comment: Remove your plugins DLLs and try again it, if that works then one of them is crashing Unity.

Comment: I did remove it, but that did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

Delete library in project folder and open the project again. It will reimport everything freshly again. If this doesn't help, you should probably send bug report to Unity's support, they will help

Comment: I did it and it did not change anything.

Comment: Does this characterize a bug? Am I not doing nothing wrong? How do you usually import something or open some project in unity?

Comment: Try Deleting all folders like library, projectsettings, obj, temp excluding Assets folder and try importing it again. Although u will lose some settings but see if reimporting assets works this time.

Comment: Just report a bug through bug reporter, attach your project, post your bug id here, I will look into it ;) EDIT: Unity should always open a project, if not, it's a bug. I'm not sure if you have something special there that it doesn't open the project